# How to get each index of one or more of an array's dimensions?

Tags: arrays, julia

If I want `eachindex` but only of a specific dimension, what's a good way to accomplish this?

E.g. `x` is a 3x5x7 Array

```
x = rand(3,5,7)
```

And I'd like to get the 2nd dimension's indexes of `1:5`, ideally in a way that doesn't assume that the indexing starts at `1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `axes` function is a generic way to get that.

```
  axes(A, d)

  Return the valid range of indices for array A along dimension d.
```

```
  julia> A = fill(1, (5,6,7));
  
  julia> axes(A, 2)
  Base.OneTo(6)
```